# If before a certain hour block a day

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, if-statement, time

I'm trying to trigger something in some code that was written for me but I cant seem to get it to work.

What I need is to have a date picker block out today and before today if its before 11am and block out tomorrow and before if its after 11am. I was trying to put an if/else on the minDate in the code below but no joy.

I was assuming that I can do it with some code that I found in another post:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var startTime = new Date();
startTime.setHours(00);
startTime.setMinutes(00);
var endTime = new Date();
endTime.setHours(11);
endTime.setMinutes(00);

if ((currentTime.getTime() > startTime.getTime()) && (currentTime.getTime() < endTime.getTime())
{
   minDate: 2
} else {
   minDate: 3;
}
```

but everytime I try to put that into the code below I break it. Can anyone please help?

```
.jQuery(".dpicker").datepicker(
{
    minDate: 2,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
    {
        var date = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('#frm_field_263_container').hide();
        jQuery('#frm_field_263_container').after(
            '<img id="loading" src="loading30.gif" />'
        );
        jQuery('#frm_field_265_container').hide();
        var qantity;
        if (!jQuery('#field_6pc0y').val())
        {
            qantity = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            qantity = parseInt(jQuery('#field_6pc0y').val());
        }
        jQuery.post(frm_js.ajax_url,
        {
            'action': 'order_quantity',
            'pick_up_date': jQuery('#field_mv0ti').val(),
            'product_id': jQuery('#product_id').val(),
            'product_title': jQuery('#product_title').val()
        }, function(response)
        {
            stock = parseInt(response);
            jQuery('#field_navpp').val(response - qantity);
            jQuery('#loading').hide();
            jQuery('#frm_field_263_container').show();
            if (response - qantity < 0)
            {
                jQuery('#frm_field_265_container').show();
            }
        });
    },
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:` is used in object literal when assigning properties or as a goto label; what you want is to store your minDate in a *variable* so you can use it when creating the date picker:

```
var minDate;
var currentTimestamp = currentTime.getTime();
if (currentTimestamp > startTime.getTime() && currentTimestamp < endTime.getTime()) {
   minDate = 2;
} else {
   minDate = 3;
}

jQuery(".dpicker").datepicker({
  minDate: minDate,
  // etc...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping a rookie out.  That's what I was missing!